# I have 2 hours values in PHP, how can I run a foreach loop to get all hours between them?

Tags: php, time

I Have Two Hours Value in PHP

```
$a = '10:00 AM';

$b = '04:00 PM';
```

How can i get all the hours between these two values.

*ie. 10:00 AM, 11:00 AM, 12:00 PM, 01:00 PM, 02:00 PM, 03:00 PM, 04:00 PM*

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)  This is not a code-writing service. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). For help with your code, please post what you have tried and a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a = '10:00 AM';
$b = '04:00 PM';

$aStr = strtotime($a);
$bStr = strtotime($b);

for ($i=$aStr; $i<=$bStr; $i+=3600)
{
    echo date('h:i A', $i) . '<br>';
}
```

outputs

```
10:00 AM
11:00 AM
12:00 PM
01:00 PM
02:00 PM
03:00 PM
04:00 PM
```